# Ошибка "PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening" после перехода с php5.6 на php7.2

Tags: php, php7, php5

при чистой установке панели управления сервером, на ней предустановлен php 7.2.24, ранее же стоял php 5.6.30, сайт на нем превосходно работал.

Сейчас же сайт выдает 500 ошибку 
Запись в логах

```
[php7:error] [pid 8152] [client 007.002.002.47:34084] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/mydomen.com/public_html/index.php/../core/engine.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/mydomen.com/public_html/index.php on line 5
```

Сам index.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../core/engine.php';

function dump($data, $end = 0)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    if($end == 1)
        exit();
}

engine::i();
```

строка о которой говориться в логах:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../core/engine.php';
```

Понимаю, что вероятнее всего это связано с совместимостью, но возможно кто то подскажет как исправить этот момент?
Спасибо

Comment: А если заменить `dirname(__FILE__)` на `__DIR__`?

Comment: Та же ошибка, различий в логах нет

Comment: А что на счет веб сервера, при смене php 5.6 на 7 вы версию сервера то хоть меняли? Про совместимость читали? Ошибка 500 как раз таки ошибка веб сервера на сколько я знаю а не php. А тот в свою очередь может ругаться на несовместимость в php.

Comment: Ранее на сервера vestaCp стоял php5.6, его туда ставил админ сервера, так как в самой весте это простыми методами не сделать, при установке же стоковой весты там стоит 7.2.

Comment: Вам нужно по шагам перебирать и пересматривать модули совместимости, скорее всего получилось так, что вы обновили 1 компонент но забыли что-то еще, зависимости так сказать, начинайте читать что нужно для работы панели, смотрите какие версии php, mysql и веб сервера используются с какими модулями и что нужно для работы панели, в общем мне кажется нужно ковыряться и ковыряться с настройками чтобы найти ту собаку, которая у вас зарыта.

Comment: Спасибо, понимаю, что где то в этом дело, но я не обновлял весту
У меня сервер на digitalocean, я создал новую каплю и туда установил чистую весту, ну то есть, по идее в ней с коробки уже должно быть все готово к работе, по этому и зациклился на этой ошибке в логах, так как это единственная ошибка которая меня встретила после установки сайта на новый сервер

Comment: Если же заменить дефолтный index.php на тестовый и в нем например через эчо, вывести текст, то никаких ошибок нет, по этому думаю, что баг с сайтом

Comment: Подправил конфиг апача
Удалив следующе строки:
php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/mydomen.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
И перезапустив apache2

Comment: а вы `dirname(__FILE__)` целиком на `__DIR__` заменили, или только `__FILE__` ? если целиком, то лог в студию

Comment: Целиком, лог идентичен получался